# on vim how to change comments to print functions

Tags: python, vim

I have a python code in the following format

```
# some description of the code
for item in items:
    do something with the items
```

I want to make the comments to print statements using vim.

```
print('some description of the code')
for item in items:
    do something with the items
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following vim command will do the trick:

```
:%s/#\s*\(.*\)/print('\1')/
```

Here:

- `:%s/.../.../` performs a regex substitution on all lines;
- `#\s*\(.*\)` matches a pounds sign followed by optional spaces followed by the text of a comment;
- `print('\1')` replaces the entire line with a statement printing the text of the comment it replaces.